# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5196452 bytes) in wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1811

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP site with `openhouse-and-openroad` theme and [Toolset Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) plugin.

There are 30k posts in my site. (318990 rows in `posts` table, 336982 rows in postmeta table).

Its because I have around 15-20 images for each post, (each image makes a new row in `posts` table)

I know the memory related issue is asked several times on SO and WP forums, but all people suggest is to increase memory limit, but I do not want to increase that. Because the whole webite is deployed on my localhost (Core i7, 8 GB RAM) so it should load fine here.

**REAL PROBLEM**

Other pages on my site loads fine, except the one with single post, it takes way too long, maybe 1 minute. Can someone tell me what could be wrong?

Is that true that WP cannot handle such number of posts (more than 20k)?

I tried every cache plugin, but that single post page does not load at all.

Comment: Without more information it seems like the post being loaded to the output buffer exceeds your maximum memory limit

Comment: Is there something like `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` in "single.php" of your template? Have you tried to limit the loop by a counter?

Comment: yes there is, i removed that loop too. but no affect

Comment: Pagination.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928

Comment: You should install xdebug on a development server and profile the run of single post to find the resource consuming parts of the code. Cachegrind is a viewer for the resulting profiler files.

Comment: You could also try increasing php's memory_limit in php.ini.

Comment: Have you tried other templates and plugin deactivation?  Also think about inconsistent data leading to infinite  recursion.

Comment: FWIW - this may have nothing to do with resources but code logic itself. I once received this error with a badly defined array if I remember from reading in a csv file!

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone hey, that was issue I didnt noticed, you can post it as answer, there was one more issue as well, please post it as answer, and i will edit your answer to add another thing so it will be helpful for future readers

Answer (score 0):

> Because the whole webite is deployed on my localhost (Core i7, 8 GB
>   RAM) so it should load fine here.

That's not really relevant to the PHP memory limit. The PHP memory limit is frequently set at a much lower value - perhaps 128M. While it sounds like you're trying to increase the efficiency of your site with some measures, it may have just grown beyond the requirements of your current PHP memory limit. I recommend checking out your php.ini and seeing what the current limit is. I'd try adding about 128M to 256M of memory to the limit just to test out and see if that works. Make sure to restart Apache (probably gracefully) as well.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use an IDE, e.g. Netbeans/PHP, in conjunction with xdebug. Enable the profiling option in xdebug and inspect the resource consumption of the parts in the code. Cachegrind is a viewer for the generated profiling data files.

The described behavior might be caused by data inconsistencies leading to an infinite recursion.

You could also test different themes and temporarily disable some plugins.